# How to get SQL Query with parameter values from TypedQuery?

Tags: java, spring, criteria-api, nativequery

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the **(Native) SQL Query, with parameter values**, from a TypedQuery. The code would be something like:

```
public String getNativeSQLString(){
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Foo> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Foo.class);
    Root<Foo> root = criteriaQuery.from(Foo);

    criteriaQuery.select(root);
    criteriaQuery.where(getPredicatesArray());
    TypedQuery<GhSummary> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    // magic to transform typedQuery to Native SQL

    return nativeSql;
}
```

An example of return would be: `"SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = 2 AND name IN ('name1', 'name2') ORDER BY name DESC"`.

I'm aware that using `String sqlQueryString = new BasicFormatterImpl().format(typedQuery.unwrap(Query.class).getQueryString());` I'm able to retrieve the HQL `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id =:param0 AND name IN (:param1, :param2) ORDER BY name DESC`, but it does not contain the values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope log4j configuration is enough for that purpose.
https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/